# how to format a float for output so the result is readable?

Tags: python, floating-point

My question pertains to formatting a floating point number in a form that is human readable.

For instance in the following example, the result is a float, and I think I have made a mistake on the location of where the truncation is taking place. You will find it is on the very last line of code.

Astronomers tend to use 0.12345 Earth weight or Jupiter weight, depending on the class of planet.

Thank you for looking into this, I appreciate your time.

```
#Planet mass relator
#A command-line program written by Anis Ali Khan

#Customary Greeting
greeting_string = "Have you found an Earth-like planet?\n\n This program lets your enter the weight in Kg\n to know it in terms we can relate to.\n"
hint_string = "For example, the weight of the Earth's moon, Luna is 7.35e22\n"

print(greeting_string)
print(hint_string)

#Earth Mass

earth_mass = 5.9742e24      #in Kg

#Jupiter Mass not yet implemented
#Jupiter Mass

#jupiter_mass = 1.898e27        #in Kg

prompt_text = 'Please enter the mass of the planet that was discovered in Kg: '
found_planet_mass = float(input(prompt_text))

ratio_decimal = 0
#ratio_fraction = []

found_relative_to_earth = float(found_planet_mass / earth_mass)

results_text_Earth = 'The planet you found weighs {m1} times the weight of the Earth\n'.format(m1=found_relative_to_earth) 

print(results_text_Earth.format('.5g')) #give 5 significant digits
```

Comment: what's the result you expect?

Comment: Taking the example of the Earth's moon, if I present the result as:

"The moon has a weight 0.012 times that of the Earth" 

I think to most educated people, this should be understandable as 12/1000s the weight. Mind you, if this is presented as:

"The moon has a weight 0.01230122 times that of the Earth"

It is more difficult to read and make sense of...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the format identifier (`5g`) in your first format statement. The format in your `print` statement does nothing:

```
results_text_Earth = 'The planet you found weighs {m1:5g} times the weight of the Earth\n'.format(m1=found_relative_to_earth) 

print(results_text_Earth)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this this will work for you:

```
found_relative_to_earth = float(found_planet_mass / earth_mass)

results_text_Earth = 'The planet you found weighs {m1:0.5f} times the weight of the Earth\n'.format(m1=found_relative_to_earth) 

print(results_text_Earth)
```